# Visual flow concatenate datefield and time field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, datetime

How can I concatenate a datefield and a timefield?

I tried it with a formulafield and the code below, but it does n't work. Datefield (Format Date) / Timefield (Format Time). The flow runs fine, but the new datetime not appear in Salesforce.

```
DATETIMEVALUE(
TEXT(YEAR({!$Record.datefield__c}))
+ "-" +
TEXT(MONTH({!$Record.datefield__c}))
+ "-" +
TEXT(DAY({!$Record.datefield__c}))
+ " " +
{!$Record.timefield__c}
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `DATETIMEVALUE`? Can you not use a formula of Data Type `Text`?

Comment: I need the Datetimevalue because the field is necessary to add a event.

Comment: Sp `TEXT(YEAR(datefield__c)) & '-' & TEXT(MONTH(datefield__c)) & '-' & TEXT(DAY(datefield__c)) & ' ' & TEXT(timefield__c)` would not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for summertime

```
(DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(YEAR({!$Record.datefield__c}))&"-"&TEXT(MONTH({!$Record.datefield__c__c})) &"-" &TEXT(DAY({!$Record.datefield__c}))&" "&{!$Record.timefield__c}))-0.0833
```